# xstream multithread instance

Tags: multithreading, xstream

I want to an instance to handle XML string in multi-thread environment.
But in official document:XStream is not thread-safe while it is configured. Unfortunately, an annotation is defining a change in configuration that is now applied while object marshalling is processed.
So I want to share the xStream instance by Class. Is it safe?
I wonder if the use is correct. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
private static Map<Class<?>, XStream> xStreamMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Class<?>, XStream>());

private static XStream getXStreamInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (xStreamMap.containsKey(clazz)) {
        return xStreamMap.get(clazz);
    }
    synchronized (clazz) {
        if (xStreamMap.containsKey(clazz)) {
            return xStreamMap.get(clazz);
        }
        XStream xStream = new XStream(new XppDriver(new NoNameCoder()));
        xStream.ignoreUnknownElements();
        xStream.processAnnotations(clazz);
        xStreamMap.put(clazz, xStream);
        return xStream;
    }
}

public static Object fromXML(String xml, final Class type) throws AppExceptionEx {
    try {
        return getXStreamInstance(type).fromXML(xml);
    } catch (XStreamException e) {
        throw new AppExceptionEx(ErrorNum.XML_ERROR,e.getMessage());
    }

}


public static String toXml(Object obj) throws AppExceptionEx {
    try {
        return getXStreamInstance(obj.getClass()).toXML(obj);
    } catch (XStreamException e) {
        throw new AppExceptionEx(ErrorNum.MAKE_XML_ERROR,
                ErrorNum.MAKE_XML_ERROR_MSG);
    }

}
```